# Eclipse, Maven and Spring

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, maven

I wanted to learn something about Spring and Maven, so I created sample Maven project in Eclipse and I chosen webapp archetype, but it created only src/main/resources and src/main/webapp folders, I am wondering why it didn't create src/main/java, also how can I add folder so the Maven will recognize it? Because when I manually create src/main/java folder, it isn't recognized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to create `src/main/java` folder and maven will automatically recognize it.
To make your project is recognize by eclipse, you can run `mvn eclipse:eclipse` at the root of the project.

[Here](https://github.com/paukiatwee/webapp-bootstrap) is the sample webapp based on maven, spring and JPA2(hibernate)

Comment: Apache Maven Plugin is retired. Apache advises to use m2e (Eclipse Maven Integration) . http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-eclipse-plugin/